# #VB.NET "Datagridview.datasource = datatable" do not add the columns from datatable to the grid

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datatable

I have a class property dealing with datagridview like as shown below:

```
Public Shared Property DetailGrid() As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
    Get
        Return _DetailGrid
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView)
        _DetailGrid = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Now I am instanciating this dataridview in the class constructor as:

```
  Public Sub New()
    _DetailGrid = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
End Sub
```

And I am populating this "DetailGrid" datagridview on my winform. On the Winform, first I am creating the object of the above class containing the "DetailGrid" property and then TRYING to populate this "Detail Grid" as shown below.

```
Private Sub PopulateDetailGrid()
    Dim TextBoxCell As DataGridViewTextBoxCell
    Dim dc_Category As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
    Dim dc_Notes As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
    Dim strSQL As String = ""

    Try
        DetailGrid.DataSource = Nothing
        StrClosedYrs = BuildClosedYrsStr()
        'SearchStr = IIf(InStr(txtSearchText, "Multiple Searches Seperated By Comma") > 0, "", Trim(txtSearchText))
        dc_Category = GetComboBoxColumn_Category()
        dc_Notes = GetComboBoxColumn_Notes()
        DetailGrid.Columns.Add(dc_Category)
        DetailGrid.Columns.Add(dc_Notes)

        Using Connection = GetConnection()
            dt = New DataTable
            strSQL = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Fn_GetData(CONVERT(DATETIME,'" & dtpFrom & "',105), CONVERT(DATETIME,'" & dtpTo & "',105), '" & Categories & "', '" & SearchStr & "')"
            da = New SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, Connection)
            da.Fill(dt)
            da.Dispose()
        End Using

        DetailGrid.DataSource = dt
        DetailGrid.AutoResizeColumns()
        DetailGrid.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill
        DetailGrid.AllowUserToAddRows = False

        DetailGrid.Columns("hKey").Visible = False
```

.
.
.
    End Sub

In the above code, when I say "DetailGrid.Datasource = dt" code won't show any error but when I go and check the column count of the "DetailGrid" it shows me only two columns that I added manually in above mentioned "PopulateDetailGrid" function.

And then the error is thrown on line DetailGrid.Columns("hKey").Visible
 = False.

Actually column "hkey" is the part of datatable that is bound to the DetailGrid.

I am not getting why this is behaving strangely. Please help me on this.

Comment: Check that `_DetailGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = true`

Comment: What error did you get? Exception message, Stack trace?

Comment: Try removing the line : da.Dispose().  I think the dataadapter is still needed.